# Using std::unique() on a std::vector<std::unordered_set<T>>

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stl

Here's my problem : I have a `std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>`. Some of those unordered sets are equal but not in the same order (I know order is ambiguous in an unordered_set). To remove duplicates (in the mathematical sense of set, for example {1,3,2} == {3,2,1}) I thought about using `std::unique()`, but that doesn't work. After searching I even noticed that the data in the vector needs to be sorted, which doesn't make sense in this case. Is there a function that remove duplicates in a `std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>`? I could do it myself I just want to know if I missed something in the stl. Also, if you know how to solve this problem using different containers then let me know. Efficiency is not an big issue here, in this context there are no more than 200 elements in that vector.

TLDR; How to I remove duplicates in `std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>>`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `unordered_set` over a `set`?  If you used a `set` two sets containing the same elements would have the same order.

Comment: You can remove the duplicates in O(n^2) time by comparing (for equality) each array element with each other array element.

Answer (score 2):

> Efficiency is not an big issue here

Then let's go wild! `set` has `operator<` defined, so let's just build them up on the fly!

```
std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> v = ...;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs){
    return std::set<int>(lhs.begin(), lhs.end()) <
        std::set<int>(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
});
v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

That's certainly pretty bad as far as runtime goes, but it works!

---

Or you could make an `unordered_set<unordered_set<int>>` and come up with a Hash that's independent of ordering so that you don't have to do any of this to begin with.

Comment: If efficiency matters I think it would be easier to use `boost::multi_index` and have unordered and ordered access at the same time.

Comment: Doesn't `std::unique` require the same lambda to detect duplicates?

Comment: @Slava The predicate for `unique` is to compare two elements for equality. `unordered_set` is already EqualityComparable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I followed n.m advice as I think it really was the simplest.
Looks like this :

```
std::vector<std::set<int>> resultP;
...............................................
// Remove the duplicate (without order), we want combinations not permutations.
std::vector<std::set<int>> resultC;
bool permAlreadyThere = false;
for (auto& perm : resultP)
{
    for (auto& comb : resultC)
    {
        if (perm == comb)
        {
            permAlreadyThere = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!permAlreadyThere) resultC.push_back(perm);
    permAlreadyThere = false;
}
```